# how to remove concatenated data in localStorage

Tags: javascript, json, html, listbox, local-storage

I'm using localStorage to store some data and all the data are concatenated separated by \n. I want to remove specific data in localStorage and i'm using listbox to display all the data.

example {"rowdata":"data1\ndata2\ndata3"} // the three data are stored in localStorage, the key of rowdata in the localStorage is storedata and the rowdata is the value of storedata that have three data concatenated.

is there an easy way to remove the selected data, example i want to remove data3. i'm using google chrome browser..

code for display:

```
function populate(){
for(i=0; i<rowdata.length; i++){
var select = document.getElementById("test"); // id of the listbox
var splitRow = rowdata.split("\n");
var row = splitRow[i];
if(row != undefined)
select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(row);
}
}
```

code for remove:

```
function removeSelectedItem(){
var htmlSelect=document.getElementById('test'); // id of the listbox
if(htmlSelect.options.length == 0)
{
alert('You have already removed all list items');
return false;
{
var optionToRemove = htmlSelect.options.selectedIndex;
htmlSelect.remove(optionToRemove);
if(htmlSelect.options.length > 0)
{
htmlSelect.options[0].selected=true;
{
alert('The selected data has been removed successfully');
return true;
}
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I clearly understood the question, but if you just need to update state if `rowdata` variable then try put the code below before removing an option from select in RemoveSelectedItem (man, start function names with lowercase!):

```
rowdata = ("\n" + rowdata + "\n").replace("\n" + htmlSelect.options[htmlSelect.options.selectedIndex].innerHTML + "\n", "").trim()
```

Comment: Thanks man, i want to remove the data in localStorage but i have no idea how to remove the concatenated data...

Comment: `localStorage[key] = new_update_concatenated_value`. Use `JSON.parse`/`JSON.stringify` on demand if you store values in json format.